# Python - Caesar Cipher

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to Python and thought I'd try to make a Caesar cipher and could use some help with my code. It looks like this:

```
def cipher(input):
    input = input.lower()  #don't mind capital letters
    output = []
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    steps = int(raw_input('How many steps? >> '))

    for i in input:
        if i == ' ':  #for space
            output.append(' ')
        else:
            pos = alphabet.index(i) + steps
            if pos >= 25:  #for out-of-range
                pos -= 26

        output.append(alphabet[pos])

    print 'The ciphered message: ', ''.join(output)


input = raw_input('Write your message. >> ')
cipher(input)
```

It seems to work a bit, but not fully, when it comes to spaces.

This is what I get:

```
Write your message. >> abc abc
How many steps? >> 1
The ciphered message:  bcd dbcd
```

I don't quite understand where the extra letter (d, in this case) in the output comes from.

Thankful for any help.

Comment: You don't need to write `'abc[...]xyz'`. Just use [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase).

Answer (score 4):

Your indentation is incorrect:

```
for i in input:
    if i == ' ':  #for space
        output.append(' ')
    else:
        pos = alphabet.index(i) + steps
        if pos >= 25:  #for out-of-range
            pos -= 26

    output.append(alphabet[pos]) # note here
```

You `append` to the `output` *whether or not `i` is a space*. This would break completely if the first character was a space (`NameError`, as `pos` is not yet assigned), but just causes repeats elsewhere in the string.

Change to:

```
for i in input:
    if i == ' ':  #for space
        output.append(' ')
    else:
        pos = alphabet.index(i) + steps
        if pos >= 25:  #for out-of-range
            pos -= 26
        output.append(alphabet[pos]) # now inside 'else'
```

Note you can also simplify your `out-of-range`:

```
pos = (alphabet.index(i) + steps) % 26
```

Comment: @user3781209 if it solves your problem, please accept and +1 this answer.

Comment: @m.wasowki I tried, but I don't seem to be allowed to give upvotes.. My reputation is too low.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
output.append(alphabet[pos])
```

should be inside the else block. In case of `i == ' '`, the `output.append` is run twice

Answer (score 0):

### Caesar Cipher in 2 lines, just for fun

```
rot3 = dict(zip(map(ord, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc'))

'tiberivs clavdivs caesar'.translate(rot3)
```