# Caesar cipher only printing last letter

Tags: python

Whenever I run it, only the last letter is shifted by the shift number. For example, if I'm shifting "you" by 3 letters, only "x" instead of "brx" is printed
How can I fix this?

```
alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',
         'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
         'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',
         'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']


def caesarShift(message):
    for char in message:
        if char == ' ':
            pass
        else:
            ind = alpha.index(char)
            newind = int(ind) + int(shift)
            shiftedChar = alpha[newind]
    return shiftedChar


message = input('Enter message here: ')
shift = input('Enter shift number: ')
print(caesarShift(message))
```

Comment: Since your function returns `shiftedChar` (which is presumably a single character), why are you surprised that it is only printing a single character? If you want a whole string, you should return a whole string.

Comment: Also define `shiftedChar` outside for loop like `shiftedChar = ''`. Otherwise for a string with nothing but spaces will generate error

Comment: Also why you are doing this - `list(message)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Caesar Cipher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733819/python-caesar-cipher)

Answer (score 0):

Create `shifterChar` upfront, and add letters to it like this:

```
def caesarShift(message):
    list(message)
    shiftedChar = ''
    for char in message:
        if char == ' ':
            pass
        else:
            ind = alpha.index(char)
            newind = int(ind) + int(shift)
            shiftedChar += alpha[newind]
    return shiftedChar
```

Comment: so, what would shifting the message `"xyz"` by a shift number of 300 give using your suggestion?

Comment: `alpha` contains 52 elements only, so your solution will raise an `IndexError`!

Comment: Using modular arithmetic will also help to reduce the size of list `alpha` to 26

Comment: Also a check if `char` is in `alpha` will help to avoid other non-alphabet characters too

Comment: I am not saying that I solved whole task of creating ceaser-cipher. The question was focused on shifting only last letter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def shiftCeasar(message, shift):
    # just an easy way to get from a to z...
    a_z = map(chr, range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1))

    _ = lambda x: a_z[(shift + a_z.index(x))%26]
    return ''.join([_(x) if x != ' ' else x for x in message])
```

Using it:

```
In [11]: shiftCeasar('this is a message', 0)
Out[11]: 'this is a message'
In [12]: shiftCeasar('this is a message', 11)
Out[12]: 'estd td l xpddlrp'
In [13]: shiftCeasar('this is a message', 2600)
Out[13]: 'this is a message'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this solution:

```
alpha = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)]

def caesarShift(message, shift):
    return ''.join([char if not char.isalpha() 
                    else alpha[(alpha.index(char)+shift)%26] 
                    for char in message])
```

Which gives:

```
In [1]: caesarShift('you', 3)
Out[1]: 'brx'
```