# How can i offset a string in python?

Tags: python, string, list

This is a codecademy challenge, i am trying to offset the letters in the input string in relation to the english alphabet. lets say if we enter d with an offset of 3 it should return a. What am i doing wrong ?
I am new to python i started 3 days ago because of the quarantine, love it so far.

```
import string
a = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

word = "assa"
i = ""
j= ""
x = 0

for j in a:
    for i in word:
        if i == j:
            x = (int(a.index(j)) - 10)
            z = str(a[x])
        sol = word.replace(i,z)


print(sol)
#def cipher(word):
```

Comment: So basically you want to create a caesar cipher?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Caesar Cipher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733819/python-caesar-cipher)

Comment: yes @SilverMonkey

Answer (score 1):

`sol = word.replace(i,z)`

Every time, this goes back to the *original* value of `word`, figures out the result of making the replacement, and gives the name `sol` to the result. For your general approach to work, you would need to rename the result as `word`.

When you do this, you should *not* loop over the characters in `word`. `.replace(i, z)` already replaces *every* appearance of `i` with `z` (since `i == j`, you could equivalently have used `j`). It is also a [bad idea to modify the thing you are looping over](https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/thou-shalt-not-modify-a-list-during-iteration/).

However, there is a much most straightforward way to implement this entire solution, using `str.translate` and `str.maketrans` - [see for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886947/caesar-cipher-function-in-python).

Comment: For what it's worth the OP is not modifying the thing they are looping over. You can't really do that with immutable strings.

Comment: I m trying to figure it out without looking at the whole answer, to get the logic of the thing @MarkMeyer